# StringMapTypeDeserializer (null) - Property '_' does not exist on type

Tags: servicestack

I recently deployed a new service and started getting the above error.
The service works, but I get the error reported in my logs.

2013-05-03 09:56:36,455 [51] WARN ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer (null) - Property '_' does not exist on type 'Services.Web.StatusList'

Here are the two types:

```cs
public class StatusList : IReturn>
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class ComboItemResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual service Get just does a simple linq query. Like I said, it works when you call the api.  I just get the above error in my logs.

Version 3.9.43 - Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an issue. It's just a warning which states that "_" parameter doesn't exist. Usually this parameter is set by jQuery ajax requests to eliminate browser cache, e.g.:
`http://yourhost/api/service?_=1367679839904`

For more details see: 
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/Serialization/StringMapTypeDeserializer.cs#L102-L105

Comment: Thanks for response.  It is only a problem because it shows up in my logs, which is not good.   Understand you guys are addressing it anyway (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/643#issuecomment-17434684) so that is great.  Thanks.